# Structuring CIFAR100 for resnet18

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

This will probably be a basic question since I am starting with computer vision. I am trying to use resnet18 from pytorch and work with CIFAR-100 dataset. Single image has size 3x32x32 and the model cannot forward this throwing error. It can process arrays of size 224, 128, 64. How should I structure my images to process them with resnet18 specifically (not other arch).

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch offers a range of transformations and you can simply apply a transformation to resize your images when loading your data. For example by using these transforms (using CIFAR10 as an example here which comes with 3x32x32 images too):

```
# transform for train data
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

# transform for test data
transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                 std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

# load data and apply transforms
train_data = datasets.CIFAR10('data', train=True,
                              download=True, transform=transform_train)
test_data = datasets.CIFAR10('data', train=False,
                             download=True, transform=transform_test)
```

Both, `transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224)` and `transforms.Resize(224)` give the desired size. (the random cropping is applied as [data augmentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-deep-learning-4fe21d1a4eb9) to further diversify training data) You will find more details on available transforms in the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html?highlight=transforms).

As a side note: the size requirement is the same for all [pre-trained models in PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html) - not just Resnet18:

> All pre-trained models expect input images normalized in the same way, i.e. mini-batches of 3-channel RGB images of shape (3 x H x W), where H and W are expected to be at least 224. The images have to be loaded in to a range of [0, 1] and then normalized using mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406] and std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225].